# How to create a localized backup server Using Windows server?

Tags: windows, active-directory, backup

My Organization wants to store every PC data to a storage, we have a windows server and a shared SMB storage, i want to configure that server to a backup server that will perform a automatic scheduled backup for each and every PC in our office. Is it possible to do it using Windows server using Active Directive or any other Microsoft tools?

I have Tried an open source tools called urbackup but they think that is not safe cause it is an open source solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may force users to save files on the new file server with group policy redirection (start menu,documents etc) settings so when they save the files they actually use the file server a central file storage instead of individual PC storage locations. In this case file server should be clustered and backed up to other media regularly.

You may have to add File Server Resource Manager component on the file server (assuming Windows Server) to apply quota and file type etc restrictions to users, and get storage reporting.

Another option
You may deploy a Map Network Drive setting H: that points to \server\userbackup share, then deploy scheduled tasks with group policy to set periodic backup user files. You may use xcopy in the scheduled task to copy files with original permissions intact, to copy only changed files etc. to \server\userbackup%username% directory. In this case the risk is if you set the scheduled task to run at 19:00 everyday and the PC is shut down at 18:00 the backups may delay, or if the scheduled task runs in the daytime, large bandwidth consumptions may occur.

You should also take necessary precautions for SMB security since SMB traffic will grow as outlined in the references below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/smb-secure-traffic?source=recommendations
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/smb-secure-traffic